# Foreach with 2 $i

Tags: php

I'm trying to run 4 identical queries with different numbers, like so:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $sql[$i] = "SELECT * FROM whatever";
    $sql[$i.$i] = "SELECT * FROM whatever2";
    $res[$i] = mysql_query($sql[$i]);
    $res[$i.$i] = mysql_query($sql[$i.$i];

    while ($row[$i] = mysql_fetch_array($res[$i]))
    {
        $val[$i] = $row[$i]['Col1'];
    }

    while ($row[$i.$i] = mysql_fetch_array($res[$i.$i]))
    {
        $val[$i.$i] = $row[$i.$i]['Col2'];
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work. If i include `echo $val[$i.$i]` in that `for` it echoes nothing.
So I guess my real question is how would I overcome this? I need to run that query 4 times, where `$i=1` to `$i = 4`, so I get `$val1, $val2, $val3, $val4`. Why can't I declare values with `$row[$i.$i]`?

PS I know I shouldn't use SQL, I was hired to fix stuff =)

Comment: How are you going to tell the difference between `$sql[11]` ($i = 1, $i . $i = 11) and `$sql[11]` ($i = 11)? This is a bad way of doing this.

Comment: Why not use and array, such as `$sql[$i][$i]`?

Comment: Because the queries themselves have it as a condition. `WHERE ID = '$i'` is a part of it =)

Answer (score 3):

That's just wrong. Why don't you use $sql1[$i] and $sql2[$i] ?
If you go to 11 $i.$i when i = 1 and $i when i = 11 will collide.

Comment: It might also have issues with `08` being interpreted as an octal number, thanks to the leading 0.

Comment: This is only for 4, as you can see `$i<5` I'm trying to mark the sql, results and variables in the same manner, so for `$i=1` I'd get `$var1` as my output

Comment: If you really want to use array use $sql[2*$i] and $sql[2*$i+1] this way you avoid any collision.